# Is there a general business equivalent of "stage names" or "pen names"

Tags: united-states, privacy, business, identification

And by that I mean: a situation where an individual can conduct their general business activities privately within a proprietorship under a fictitious "pseudonym" or via proxy? Though I'd imagine if so there would at least be provisions within the law that would allow for one's identity to be revealed by subpoena or some other means in cases that constitute personal legal liability—especially under criminal investigations.

Comment: You want a business name?

Comment: I suppose but I'm unsure of the limitations that constrain them especially regarding legal (mostly concerning civil liability) matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to use a company name rather than your own.

Normally, that is done with a dba, or doing business as. Check this site:
https://www.fundera.com/blog/what-is-dba

When your business is a sole proprietorship, meaning its not a legally registered corporation, you file for a DBA.

Registered Corporations pick a name while registering and don't have to have a DBA, but can if they want.

Comment: Thank you; this appears to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Good deal. I hope it helps.

Comment: The formal legal name for a DBA is a "trade name".

Comment: This may not achieve the goal of conducting business "privately".  In fact, in some jurisdictions (e.g. California), such filings must actually be published in a newspaper, so that the entire general public is (in principle) informed of the real name of the person behind the business.

Comment: Even when a DBA registration need not be published, in most US states (perhaps all) it is a public record, and any one may easily learn that John Doe is the sole proprietor of Zippy Consultants (for example) It does allow a bank account in the trade name, and generally helps keep business dealings separate from personal ones.